# Herokuapp launching fails, despite git push success, page opens with following title: Error and displays "Not Found" in HTML

Tags: node.js, heroku, react-redux, npm-scripts

So I was following this awesome tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71wSzpLyW9k (I started from the very beginning of the series, following along, I'm new to React/Redux). Anyway, so everything worked, all git add, commit and push worked. But at the same time, when I go to the URL to launch the app, it opens up a page saying "Not found". That is all.

Here's a log of when I run git push heroku master:

```
Enumerating objects: 7657, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7657/7657), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7064/7064), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7657/7657), 5.45 MiB | 1.10 MiB/s, done.
Total 7657 (delta 2408), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 8.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.12.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.4.1
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:
remote:        > nodemon@1.18.4 postinstall /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/nodemon
remote:        > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
remote:
remote:        Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
remote:        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
remote:
remote:        body-parser@1.18.3 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/body-parser
remote:        bytes@3.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/bytes
remote:        content-type@1.0.4 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/content-type
remote:        debug@2.6.9 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/debug
remote:        ms@2.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/ms
remote:        depd@1.1.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/depd
remote:        http-errors@1.6.3 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/http-errors
remote:        inherits@2.0.3 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/inherits
remote:        setprototypeof@1.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/setprototypeof
remote:        statuses@1.5.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/statuses
remote:        iconv-lite@0.4.23 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/iconv-lite
remote:        safer-buffer@2.1.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/safer-buffer
remote:        on-finished@2.3.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/on-finished
remote:        ee-first@1.1.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/ee-first
remote:        qs@6.5.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/qs
remote:        raw-body@2.3.3 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/raw-body
remote:        unpipe@1.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/unpipe
remote:        type-is@1.6.16 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/type-is
remote:        media-typer@0.3.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/media-typer
remote:        mime-types@2.1.20 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mime-types
remote:        mime-db@1.36.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mime-db
remote:        concurrently@4.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/concurrently
remote:        chalk@2.4.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/chalk
remote:        ansi-styles@3.2.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/ansi-styles
remote:        color-convert@1.9.3 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/color-convert
remote:        color-name@1.1.3 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/color-name
remote:        escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/escape-string-regexp
remote:        supports-color@5.5.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/supports-color
remote:        has-flag@3.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/has-flag
remote:        date-fns@1.29.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/date-fns
remote:        lodash@4.17.10 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/lodash
remote:        read-pkg@4.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/read-pkg
remote:        normalize-package-data@2.4.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/normalize-package-data
remote:        hosted-git-info@2.7.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/hosted-git-info
remote:        is-builtin-module@1.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/is-builtin-module
remote:        builtin-modules@1.1.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/builtin-modules
remote:        semver@5.5.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/semver
remote:        validate-npm-package-license@3.0.4 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license
remote:        spdx-correct@3.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/spdx-correct
remote:        spdx-expression-parse@3.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse
remote:        spdx-exceptions@2.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/spdx-exceptions
remote:        spdx-license-ids@3.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/spdx-license-ids
remote:        parse-json@4.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/parse-json
remote:        error-ex@1.3.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/error-ex
remote:        is-arrayish@0.2.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/is-arrayish
remote:        json-parse-better-errors@1.0.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors
remote:        pify@3.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/pify
remote:        rxjs@6.2.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/rxjs
remote:        tslib@1.9.3 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/tslib
remote:        spawn-command@0.0.2-1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/spawn-command
remote:        supports-color@4.5.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/supports-color
remote:        has-flag@2.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/supports-color/node_modules/has-flag
remote:        tree-kill@1.2.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/tree-kill
remote:        yargs@12.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/yargs
remote:        cliui@4.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/cliui
remote:        string-width@2.1.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/string-width
remote:        is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point
remote:        strip-ansi@4.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/strip-ansi
remote:        ansi-regex@3.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/ansi-regex
remote:        wrap-ansi@2.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/wrap-ansi
remote:        string-width@1.0.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/wrap-ansi/node_modules/string-width
remote:        code-point-at@1.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/code-point-at
remote:        is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/wrap-ansi/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point
remote:        number-is-nan@1.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/number-is-nan
remote:        strip-ansi@3.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/wrap-ansi/node_modules/strip-ansi
remote:        ansi-regex@2.1.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/wrap-ansi/node_modules/ansi-regex
remote:        decamelize@2.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/decamelize
remote:        xregexp@4.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/xregexp
remote:        find-up@3.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/find-up
remote:        locate-path@3.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/locate-path
remote:        p-locate@3.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/p-locate
remote:        p-limit@2.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/p-limit
remote:        p-try@2.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/p-try
remote:        path-exists@3.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/path-exists
remote:        get-caller-file@1.0.3 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/get-caller-file
remote:        os-locale@2.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/os-locale
remote:        execa@0.7.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/execa
remote:        cross-spawn@5.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/cross-spawn
remote:        lru-cache@4.1.3 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/lru-cache
remote:        pseudomap@1.0.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/pseudomap
remote:        yallist@2.1.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/yallist
remote:        shebang-command@1.2.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/shebang-command
remote:        shebang-regex@1.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/shebang-regex
remote:        which@1.3.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/which
remote:        isexe@2.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/isexe
remote:        get-stream@3.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/get-stream
remote:        is-stream@1.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/is-stream
remote:        npm-run-path@2.0.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/npm-run-path
remote:        path-key@2.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/path-key
remote:        p-finally@1.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/p-finally
remote:        signal-exit@3.0.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/signal-exit
remote:        strip-eof@1.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/strip-eof
remote:        lcid@1.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/lcid
remote:        invert-kv@1.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/invert-kv
remote:        mem@1.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mem
remote:        mimic-fn@1.2.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mimic-fn
remote:        require-directory@2.1.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/require-directory
remote:        require-main-filename@1.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/require-main-filename
remote:        set-blocking@2.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/set-blocking
remote:        which-module@2.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/which-module
remote:        y18n@4.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/y18n
remote:        yargs-parser@10.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/yargs-parser
remote:        camelcase@4.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/camelcase
remote:        express@4.16.3 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/express
remote:        accepts@1.3.5 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/accepts
remote:        negotiator@0.6.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/negotiator
remote:        array-flatten@1.1.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/array-flatten
remote:        body-parser@1.18.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/express/node_modules/body-parser
remote:        iconv-lite@0.4.19 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/express/node_modules/iconv-lite
remote:        qs@6.5.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/express/node_modules/qs
remote:        raw-body@2.3.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/express/node_modules/raw-body
remote:        http-errors@1.6.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/express/node_modules/raw-body/node_modules/http-errors
remote:        depd@1.1.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/express/node_modules/raw-body/node_modules/depd
remote:        setprototypeof@1.0.3 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/express/node_modules/raw-body/node_modules/setprototypeof
remote:        statuses@1.4.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/express/node_modules/statuses
remote:        content-disposition@0.5.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/content-disposition
remote:        cookie@0.3.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/cookie
remote:        cookie-signature@1.0.6 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/cookie-signature
remote:        encodeurl@1.0.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/encodeurl
remote:        escape-html@1.0.3 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/escape-html
remote:        etag@1.8.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/etag
remote:        finalhandler@1.1.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/finalhandler
remote:        parseurl@1.3.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/parseurl
remote:        statuses@1.4.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/finalhandler/node_modules/statuses
remote:        fresh@0.5.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/fresh
remote:        merge-descriptors@1.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/merge-descriptors
remote:        methods@1.1.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/methods
remote:        path-to-regexp@0.1.7 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/path-to-regexp
remote:        proxy-addr@2.0.4 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/proxy-addr
remote:        forwarded@0.1.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/forwarded
remote:        ipaddr.js@1.8.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/ipaddr.js
remote:        range-parser@1.2.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/range-parser
remote:        safe-buffer@5.1.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/safe-buffer
remote:        send@0.16.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/send
remote:        destroy@1.0.4 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/destroy
remote:        mime@1.4.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mime
remote:        statuses@1.4.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/send/node_modules/statuses
remote:        serve-static@1.13.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/serve-static
remote:        utils-merge@1.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/utils-merge
remote:        vary@1.1.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/vary
remote:        mongoose@5.2.13 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mongoose
remote:        async@2.6.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/async
remote:        bson@1.0.9 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/bson
remote:        kareem@2.2.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/kareem
remote:        lodash.get@4.4.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/lodash.get
remote:        mongodb@3.1.4 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mongodb
remote:        mongodb-core@3.1.3 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mongodb-core
remote:        bson@1.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson
remote:        require_optional@1.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/require_optional
remote:        resolve-from@2.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/resolve-from
remote:        safe-buffer@5.1.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/safe-buffer
remote:        safe-buffer@5.1.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/safe-buffer
remote:        mongoose-legacy-pluralize@1.0.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mongoose-legacy-pluralize
remote:        mpath@0.5.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mpath
remote:        mquery@3.2.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mquery
remote:        bluebird@3.5.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/bluebird
remote:        debug@3.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mquery/node_modules/debug
remote:        regexp-clone@0.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/regexp-clone
remote:        safe-buffer@5.1.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mquery/node_modules/safe-buffer
remote:        sliced@1.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/sliced
remote:        safe-buffer@5.1.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/safe-buffer
remote:        copy-descriptor@0.1.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/copy-descriptor
remote:        get-value@2.0.6 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/get-value
remote:        path-is-inside@1.0.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/path-is-inside
remote:        pstree.remy@1.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/pstree.remy
remote:        ps-tree@1.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/ps-tree
remote:        event-stream@3.3.5 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/event-stream
remote:        duplexer@0.1.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/duplexer
remote:        from@0.1.7 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/from
remote:        map-stream@0.0.7 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/map-stream
remote:        pause-stream@0.0.11 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/pause-stream
remote:        through@2.3.8
```

... removed some of these (node_modules) otherwise it would exceed 30,000 chars...

```
remote:        is-glob@4.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/is-glob
remote:        lodash.debounce@4.0.8 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/lodash.debounce
remote:        path-is-absolute@1.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/path-is-absolute
remote:        readdirp@2.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/readdirp
remote:        graceful-fs@4.1.11 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/graceful-fs
remote:        minimatch@3.0.4 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/minimatch
remote:        readable-stream@2.3.6 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/readable-stream
remote:        core-util-is@1.0.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/core-util-is
remote:        process-nextick-args@2.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/process-nextick-args
remote:        string_decoder@1.1.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/string_decoder
remote:        util-deprecate@1.0.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/util-deprecate
remote:        set-immediate-shim@1.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/set-immediate-shim
remote:        upath@1.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/upath
remote:        ci-info@1.4.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/ci-info
remote:        configstore@3.1.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/configstore
remote:        dot-prop@4.2.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/dot-prop
remote:        is-obj@1.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/is-obj
remote:        make-dir@1.3.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/make-dir
remote:        unique-string@1.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/unique-string
remote:        crypto-random-string@1.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/crypto-random-string
remote:        write-file-atomic@2.3.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/write-file-atomic
remote:        imurmurhash@0.1.4 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/imurmurhash
remote:        xdg-basedir@3.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/xdg-basedir
remote:        create-error-class@3.0.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/create-error-class
remote:        deep-extend@0.6.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/deep-extend
remote:        duplexer3@0.1.4 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/duplexer3
remote:        global-dirs@0.1.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/global-dirs
remote:        ini@1.3.5 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/ini
remote:        got@6.7.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/got
remote:        is-redirect@1.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/is-redirect
remote:        is-retry-allowed@1.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/is-retry-allowed
remote:        lowercase-keys@1.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/lowercase-keys
remote:        timed-out@4.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/timed-out
remote:        unzip-response@2.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/unzip-response
remote:        url-parse-lax@1.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/url-parse-lax
remote:        prepend-http@1.0.4 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/prepend-http
remote:        ignore-by-default@1.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/ignore-by-default
remote:        import-lazy@2.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/import-lazy
remote:        is-installed-globally@0.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/is-installed-globally
remote:        is-path-inside@1.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/is-path-inside
remote:        is-npm@1.0.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/is-npm
remote:        latest-version@3.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/latest-version
remote:        package-json@4.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/package-json
remote:        registry-auth-token@3.3.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/registry-auth-token
remote:        rc@1.2.8 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/rc
remote:        minimist@1.2.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/minimist
remote:        strip-json-comments@2.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/strip-json-comments
remote:        registry-url@3.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/registry-url
remote:        saslprep@1.0.1 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/saslprep
remote:        semver-diff@2.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/semver-diff
remote:        undefsafe@2.0.2 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/undefsafe
remote:        update-notifier@2.5.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/update-notifier
remote:        is-ci@1.2.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/is-ci
remote:        nopt@1.0.10 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/nopt
remote:        touch@3.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/touch
remote:        nodemon@1.18.4 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/nodemon
remote:        debug@3.1.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/debug
remote:        supports-color@5.5.0 /tmp/build_7155bc3cb0b36b2e6d226716814b34dd/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/supports-color
remote:        Installing any new modules (package.json)
remote:        audited 1634 packages in 4.297s
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:
remote:
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        - node_modules
remote:
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        removed 197 packages and audited 278 packages in 3.289s
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 21M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://polar-castle-29232.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/polar-castle-29232.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

You can open up the link and see for yourself: https://polar-castle-29232.herokuapp.com/ Where do I start when going about this error? What do I need to look for?

Comment: ok, so what is the output of `git remote -v`? - that should show a 'heroku' named origin and in there will be the application name that you pushed to.

Comment: I run it and it displays this:
git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/warm-everglades-81295.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/warm-everglades-81295.git (push)
Then when I try clicking on each link, it says "Method not allowed" on the page that opens.

Comment: My feeling is that something is not working with the server?